# How to combine JS/CSS for Amazon S3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

On a regular VPS site I would use Minify to compress and combine multiple CSS/JS files so the site's only using 1 or 2 HTTP requests. A site I'm working on now has it's CSS/JS files hosted on Amazon S3 and served through Amazon CloudFront. Obviously Minify is a PHP5 app and not able to run on AWS.

I can compress the scripts easily before uploading but what's the best way to combine scripts on AWS S3 to reduce HTTP requests?

http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minify combines and minifies JS/CSs on the fly.

S3 and CloudFront serve static files - you'll have to combine and minify them yourself before you upload. It's easy enough - concat the files together and minify with [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) or [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app.html) (2 free cross-platform command-line minifiers).

It's usually convenient to have a script or build step that does this, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat a.js b.js c.js | java -jar yuicompressor-1.4.2.jar --type js -o output.min.js
```

On Windows, another excellent option is [Microsoft's Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

When CloudFront receives a cold-cache hit it requests the content from the distribution's configured origin server. In most cases a S3 bucket is configured as the origin. So the easiest way is to combine and minify your JS and CSS is to store it in S3 as part of your build/deployment process.

If you really want to minify on-the-fly you can configure CloudFront to use a "Custom Origin". In this distribution configuration cold-cache hits would be requested from your server running Minify.

See the CloudFront documentation on [creating distributions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?AboutCreatingDistributions.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to serve static content from S3/CloudFront, I would recommend compressing your content ahead of time. Personally, I use [Juicer](https://github.com/cjohansen/juicer). Once you've done that, you can `gzip -9` your production files, and upload them to S3 with a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header.

The problem with compressing on the fly is the performance hit your site takes. CloudFront custom-origin support alleviates this a bit, but it would be really easy to automate your deployments with a tool like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) that does this work for you. This is the approach I take, myself.

Answer (score 1):

New – Gzip Compression Support for Amazon CloudFront, [Check here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-gzip-compression-support-for-amazon-cloudfront/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=launches&sc_publisher=tw_go&sc_content=gzip&sc_country=global&sc_geo=global&sc_category=cloudfront&adbsc=social_launches_20151217_56478536&adbid=677615225768566785&adbpl=tw&adbpr=66780587).

**Enabling Gzip Compression**

You can enable this feature in a minute! Simply open up the CloudFront Console, locate your distribution, and set Compress Objects Automatically to Yes in the Behavior options:
[image]